# Convert VB Date() and DateAdd functions to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, vba

I have a simple VBA function that shows records from current date and anything back to 21 days old.

```
WHERE date_added between Date() and DateAdd('d', -21, Date())
```

How can I get the same effect using PHP and MySQL?

When I run code above I get this error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and DateAdd('d', -21, Date())' at line 1"

Comment: just use the same mysql query!

Comment: @Alex: He might be asking about the `DateAdd` part; the code is an odd mix of SQL and VB with no distinction made, probably because it's actually Access VBA, not VB.NET or VBScript.

Comment: @NathanTuggy maybe. but we have `DATEDIFF` with mysql. but he is not asking about mysql<->sql transition, he is asking about vb<->php ;-) :-)

Comment: @Alex: And you're certain that the distinction between SQL dialect differences and host language differences is clear? Because as an Access programmer myself I wouldn't be surprised to see someone make the mistake I described.

Comment: I am sure that  any sql query is completely isolated from the programming language. so you always can access Access db from any language that have driver. And you can request from php or VB  any sql server MS SQL, MySQL or Oracle or any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MySQL dialect, you want

```
WHERE date_added BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY
                     AND CURDATE()
```

Notice that this works correctly only if date_added is a DATE data type.  If it has a time component you want

```
WHERE date_added >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY
  AND date_added <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```